# How to change product view image design layout for a specific category only?

Tags: magento2, category, product-images, product-view, category-view

I want to only on specific category product view image design and layout change but another category product image view design and layout has been the same.

[image: this is defult product view][image: This is my changaes layout for product view , it's my requirement]